# Dash app in django-plotly-dash breaking migrate, how to stop it executing in a migrate?

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using [django-plotly-dash](https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so have a Django template that hosts a Dash app.
(The Dash app is using raw SQL queries over psycopg2)

When I do a django migrate, this dash raw SQL fails because the tables have not yet been created.

Thus halting the migrate. aka Catch22.

Anyone know if there's a way to stop the Dash apps being executed during a migrate ?

Responding to comment from Ian S (thanks)...
Here's a reduced version of the query string:

```
queryStr = '''
SELECT veh.number as veh,
       dh.rcmdh_number as dh,
from 
     rcm_rcmveh as veh,
     rcma_rcmdh as dh,
where sige.sig_id = sig.id 
      AND sig.unit_id = veh .id
      '''
cnx = psycopg2.connect(
    host=POSTGRES_ADDRESS,
    database=POSTGRES_DBNAME,
    user=POSTGRES_USERNAME,
    password=POSTGRES_PASSWORD)

df = pd.read_sql_query(queryStr, cnx)
```

The query doesn't run because rcm_rcmveh doesn't exist yet because the migration is in the process of being run.

This is in the top level of the dashapp.py module.
So thinking about it, I probably need to put it inside a function in the module so that it isn't run when the module is scanned by Django on startup ?

Comment: Can you share the part of your app that is running the raw queries?

Comment: You should move your code to a function that is not called on startup of your app. Regardless of if it messes up your migrations, running queries on start up will cause your app and any management commands you run to slow down and be inefficient

Comment: Thanks. One of those where you "almost answer it yourself by explaining it" questions :)
See Rubber Duck debugging https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging